# VNC access always types CTRL+Char

Tags: ubuntu, centos, vnc

I've installed VNC Viewer Remmina on my ubuntu 15.04 local computer. I want to access remote Centos 6 computer, VPS. Problem is when I make a long pause and when I start typing VNC make logout and when I try to login and type a char on my remote computer shows CTRL+the Char. If I try to login with other VNC client it is the same. What is problem and what is solution, except restarting the VPS? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know specifically about VNC, but some applications at times detect a "key down" event but miss the corresponding "key up" event. I have had stuck CTRL and ALT at times. When it happened to me, just tapping the modifier key in question while connected resolved the issue.

Comment: I tried it nervously many times, but result is nothing. Problem is arrised no one time! Other applications on my local computer works fine. Thanks for try!